# Why does R behave like this?

Tags: r

I use the following multiplication in R (v. R-3.6.1): 115*1.044. I get 120.1. In Excel I get 120.06. By hand I get 120.062.

I select use options(digits=4) in R, but I still get the same result: 120.1.

Why does R behave like this? I use to trust it more than Excel, but it seems that here Excel is more accurate in what it returns. Is there a way to force R to return the accurate digits I would get if multiplying by hand?

Comment: Hint: `120.1` has `digits=4`.

Comment: Thank you, David, I was naively thinking that "digits" refers to the number of decimals.

Comment: Also: Computers uses a LIMITED precision unless you go to special software packages, and maybe apply settings in those. "Standard" level calculation is often done in 32 bit floating point -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: You need to distinguish between what a number *is* from how it is *displayed*. Both R and Excel use 64-bit floats. The difference between them has nothing to do with precision, but everything to do with the *algorithms* used with those floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The function `format` has the digits option referred to the total digits of the number considered as a whole (integer and decimal part):

```
> format(115*1.044, digits = 5)
[1] "120.06"
> format(115*1.044, digits = 4)
[1] "120.1"
```

Comment: using `nsmall` with `format` rather than `digits` seems to be more what OP is asking about.